# Failed installing 'OpenKM' service

Tags: java, java-8, tomcat8, openkm

I am installing OpenKM(Open source document management system) in my Windows 10 64bit PC.
JDK: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
JRE: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_121

I have already setup a system variables JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_121

This is my command prompt installation

```
Start install process? [y/N]: y

- Downloading Tomcat: 8.5.24 ....*.... 10% ....*.... 20% ....*.... 30% ....*.... 40% ....*.... 50% ....*.... 60% ....*.... 70% ....*.... 80% ....*.... 90% ....*.... 100%
- Unzipping archive... Done!
- Downloading Extras ....*.... 10% ....*.... 20% ....*.... 30% ....*.... 40% ....*.... 50% ....*.... 60% ....*.... 70% ....*.... 80% ....*.... 90% ....*.... 100%
- Unzipping archive... Done!
- Downloading OpenKM: 6.3.8 ....*.... 10% ....*.... 20% ....*.... 30% ....*.... 40% ....*.... 50% ....*.... 60% ....*.... 70% ....*.... 80% ....*.... 90% ....*.... 100%
- Unzipping archive... Done!
- Check archive integrity... Done!
- Copy OpenKM
- Configure OpenKM

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
- Configure service Installing the service 'OpenKM' ... Using CATALINA_HOME:    "C:\tomcat-8.5.24" Using CATALINA_BASE:    "C:\tomcat-8.5.24" Using JAVA_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121" Using JRE_HOME:         "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121" Using JVM:              "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\server\jvm.dll" Failed installing 'OpenKM' service
- Directory cleanup
- Don't forget to create the database CREATE DATABASE okmdb DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_bin; CREATE USER openkm@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'FMOOgXKCGHQe'; GRANT ALL ON okmdb.* TO openkm@localhost WITH GRANT OPTION;

C:\>
```

Problem:

1. It says Failed installing 'OpenKM' service.
2. localhost:8080 is accessible but localhost:8080/OpenKM - HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Note: I have existing XAMPP Installed.

Comment: Are you running the installer as admin?

Answer (score 0):

I have an existing 'OpenKM' service already installed, to solve the issue - Uninstall using cmd as administrator.

Run this command

```
sc delete 'OpenKM'
```

inside cmd change directory to C:\tomcat-8.5.24\bin, then run this command

```
C:\tomcat-8.5.24\bin>service install
```

Result:

```
Installing the service 'OpenKM' ...
Using CATALINA_HOME:    "C:\tomcat-8.5.24"
Using CATALINA_BASE:    "C:\tomcat-8.5.24"
Using JAVA_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121"
Using JRE_HOME:         "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121"
Using JVM:              "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\server\jvm.dll"
The service 'OpenKM' has been installed.
```